# Setting Min and Max values for more than two Highchart Solid Gauges using function

Tags: javascript, highcharts, max, min, gauge

I am facing difficulty in setting Min and Max Values for my Solid Gauges in highcharts.

Please Refer my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/abhaybh/n45snkm6/

I am using yAxis for setting the range as described here:

`yAxis:
    {
        min: minData,
        max: maxData,
    },`

I want to set different ranges for different Gauges. But, they are not displaying the same range as inserted.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem here is actually in `tickAmount` attribute of `yAxis`, which is set to `2`. That makes solidgauge to round up max value in order to satisfy this number (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.max). It seems to be the easiest way to display appropriate values for each solidgauge is to use the `tickPositions` array inside `yAxis` object: `tickPositions: [minData, maxData]`. It will override behaviour of `tickInterval` and `tickPixelInterval`, and a gauge will display needable values as `min` and `max` labels. Here is your modified fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n45snkm6/1/.